# Do I need a transit visa if my layover is in Saudi Arabia

Tags: transit-visas, malaysia, saudi-arabia, tunisian-citizens

Hi I have a Tunisian passport and I'm travelling to Malaysia through Jeddah, do I need a transit visa if my layover is 5-6 hours and I don't plan to leave the airport? I also have to return the same way, is it permitted to have two layovers in Saudi Arabia if my travel is 2 weeks long ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange.  I think I'm supposed to ask you what research you've done.

According to wikipedia and timeatic, you will need a visa.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Tunisian_citizens#cite_ref-175

https://www.saudi.gov.sa/wps/portal/snp/government/servicedetails/8474

Comment: The comment above about needing a visa is incorrect. Timatic confirms that a Tunisian citizen on the way to Malaysia can transit Saudi Arabia without a visa on the conditions stated by @BritishSam in the Answer. These are the travel plans stated by the OP.

Answer (score 3):

According to [IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/), you don't need a visa under if your transit is under 12 hours.

> Passengers transiting through Dammam (DMM), **Jeddah (JED)** or Riyadh
>   (RUH) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country
>   within 12 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of
>   the airport and have documents required for the next destination.